# Angular @Input pass data from index html

Tags: angular, input

I'm trying to receive data by using @Input from HTML page.

Example -
Root Component

```
Template : "<div><comp1 value='hello'</div>"
Selector : "app-root"
```

Child Component

```
Template : "<input type='text' [value]='value'/>"
Selector : "comp1"

class{
@Input value:string;
}
```

index.html

```
<body>
<app-root></<app-root>
</body>
```

Try 1:
Result : The child component is displaying hello

Try 2:
index.html

```
<body>
<comp1 value='test'></comp1>
</body>
```

bootstrap change to ChildComponent

Result : The child component value showing nothing.

child ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-arc-chart',
  templateUrl: './arc-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./arc-chart.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class ArcChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() textValue:string = "123";

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    console.log(this.textValue);
  }

}

child html file
<input type="text" value="{{textValue}}" />
```

app ts file

```
 import {
      Component
    } from "@angular/core";


        @Component({
          selector: "app-root",
          templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
          styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
        })
        export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
          }
```

app html file

```
<div>
<app-arc-chart textValue="555"></app-arc-chart>
</div>
```

I'm expecting value change if i change the attribute value in Index.html. `<app-arc-chart textValue='hahaha'></app-arc-chart'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose @Input by '[]' just Like I did below code.

```
<div>
<app-arc-chart [textValue]="555"></app-arc-chart>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, i try before even doesn't enclosed with the bracket it was work in appcomponent.html. What i really want to do is if i change anything in index.html for the selector attribute it will reflect the value changes.

Comment: @Issac, Can you give me link of any online angular editor like StackBlitz ? So it will be useful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ronak, i think i have solved it by creating custom elements. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

**index.html** is just a simple HTML file. It isn't associated with any component. So you cannot write Angular selector or any other angular logic in it.

When the application starts, it bootstraps AppComponent (or any other component that is added as `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` in app.module,

You should have only

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

in index.html. Everything else should be in a component.

Comment: Hi, Adrita thanks for quick response, could we do something in index.html that could pass data through attribute like angular @Input? I saw some someone did in the past but I doesn't have the source code so doesn't know what he/she did. So when I use the reference of that JS, I can simply inject the selector with attribute to pass value through the attribute.